# sp_Blitz - undocumented DBCC events related to the replication marked as a finding

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sp-blitz

Recently I found in the `sp_Blitz` output new finding *'Overall Events'* in *'DBCC Events'* findings group:

```
15278 DBCC events have taken place between Aug  8 2017 12:15AM and Aug  8 2017  8:17AM. This does not include CHECKDB and other usually benign DBCC events.
```

When I digged into this and checked the default trace, I found that every minute it records entries like this:

```
dbcc incrementinstance ("SQL Replication Distribution", "Dist:Delivered Cmds/sec", @agent_name, @new_delivered_commands)
dbcc setinstance ("SQL Replication Distribution", "Dist:Delivery Latency", @agent_name, @delivery_latency)
dbcc addinstance ("SQL Replication Logreader", @agent_name)
```

It's plainly visible this is replication related, but since these commands are undocumented I am not sure whether they should come up in the trace. However, basing purely on the output it just measures the amount of commands per seconds plus the latency. I think this is nothing harmful.

So if you could possibly check your servers where you run the replication and confirm if you have these entries and the frequency is more-less the same?

The separate question is if it's normal to see such commands (and I guess it is) in the default trace, perhaps it shouldn't be considered as a finding by `sp_Blitz` and it should be grouped with other harmless `DBCC` commands already excluded in `sp_Blitz`.

We use Sentry One to monitor SQL Server, but I don't think it's monitoring replication. I think it might be something internal. There are some default alerts defined when you deploy replication (SQL Agent -> Alerts, for example: Replication Warning: Transactional replication latency (Threshold: latency)) It is basing on SQL Server error log, but the entry in the error log has to be initially triggered by something.

I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/issues/1062) on Github to cover this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brent has just replied on [Github](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/issues/1062) it is going to be excluded from the alerts.